# How to use % signs in configparser python?

Tags: python, configparser

I am writing a `config.ini` file for my python project. I want to mention the standard date format of a column.

Something like this

```
prod_db_end_date   = 2017-01-01
prod_db_end_date_format = %Y-%m-%d
```

But it interpolates something else and errors out. Could someone please let me know how to use this?

```
Error traceback - File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\configparser.py", line 443, in _interpolate_some
      "found: %r" % (rest,))
configparser.InterpolationSyntaxError: '%' must be followed by '%' or '(', found: '%Y-%m-%d'
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You have three options:

- Disable interpolation, or pick a different interpolation handler. You can set the `interpolation` option to `None` to disable interpolation for the whole file:

  ```
  ConfigParse(interpolation=None)
  ```

  See the [*Interpolation of values* section](https://docs.python.org/3/library/configparser.html#interpolation-of-values).
- Access that specific value with interpolation disabled, setting `raw=True` for the [`ConfigParser.get()` method](https://docs.python.org/3/library/configparser.html#configparser.ConfigParser.get):

  ```
  config.get('section', 'prod_db_end_date_format', raw=True)
  ```
- Double the `%` characters to `%%`:

  ```
  prod_db_end_date_format = %%Y-%%m-%%d
  ```

Comment: I'd appreciate very much if you could _comment_ which is your preferred solution and why..

Comment: @gboffi that depends on what you need to achieve; there are pros and cons to each, weigh those against your specific usecases.

Comment: If I use `interpolation=ExtendedInterpolation()` with `[GENERAL] config_date_format = %%Y-%%m-%%d` and `self.configuration['GENERAL'].get('config_date_format')` it doesn't substitute two `%%` into `%`. Have to use `.replace('%%', '%')` in `datetime.strptime` which seems hacky?

Comment: @fpopic: `ExtendedInterpolation` doesn't treat `%` as special at all, it uses a different format for interpolation. There `$` is special, and you'd have to use `$$` to get a literal dollar sign. You can just store `config_date_format = %Y-%m-%d`. This is covered in the [relevant section of the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/configparser.html#configparser.ExtendedInterpolation), see the `[Escape]` section of the example, and contrast that with the [`BasicInterpolation` section](https://docs.python.org/3/library/configparser.html#configparser.BasicInterpolation) right above it.